# Ubuntu 16.04 on virtualbox Windows Gues VM screen too small

Tags: virtualbox

on my Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo T430 laptop, I have a Windows Virtualbox Guest VM.  It worked great until I decide to move the SSD to a T450s. the new laptop display has 1920x1080 resolution. After the move the Windows Guest VM would not to on full screen. Under System Setting, the display has a max of 1535x829 resolution.

I reinstalled the Guest Addition as some postings suggested. I also enabled 3-D acceleration, and increased the Video memory to 256MB. But nothing changed.

Would anyone experienced such before share some insight as to what I should try next?

Comment: Have you tried to right-click on the Windows desktop -> Click "display settings" -> change resolution? Also, this is a question about virtualbox and would be more suited to forums like SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you. I found out also that 3-D acceleration is not necessary. It is now ok.